# Prove inequality using rank nullity theorem

Tags: linear-transformations

I have two linear functions $f:V\rightarrow W$ and $g: W\rightarrow X$ and I have to prove:

$$dim(ker(g\circ f)) \ge dim(ker(g)) + dim(V) - dim(W) $$

I already proved $$dim(ker(g\circ f)) \geq dim(ker(f))$$
$$dim(Im(g\circ f)) \le dim(Im(f))$$

I am pretty sure I need to use those two inequalities to prove the above one, but I cannot seem to come to a conclusion. Is it even possible to prove my statement by just transforming inequalities or do I need to use another fact? Any hints?

EDIT: Okay I updated the proposition, this proposition should be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u: V \rightarrow W/ \ker g$ such that $u(x)=\overline {f(x)}$.

$u(x)=0 \iff f(x) \in \ker g \iff g \circ f(x)=0$

So $\ker u = \ker ( g \circ f)$.

$\dim u(V)+ \dim \ker u= \dim V$

$u(V) \subset W/ \ker g$, so $\dim u(V) \leq \dim W- \dim \ker g$.

Then $\dim V -\dim \ker (g \circ f) \leq \dim W - \dim \ker g$.

Comment: One question: What exactly is meant by $\overline {f(x)}$ ?

Comment: $\overline{f(x)}=f(x)+\ker g \in W/ \ker g$,    $\overline{f(x)}$ is the equivalence class of $f(x)$ in $W/ \ker g$.